# i have Java rest api Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, exception

im created a rest api project java in intellij .
when i run my project i receive exception

this is my main class code :

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            ResourceConfig config = new PackagesResourceConfig("controller");
            HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:8070/",config);
            server.start();

    }
}
```

this is my calculator class code :

```
package controller;

import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

@Path("/cal")
public class Calculator {
    @Path("/sum")
    @POST
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String sum(@QueryParam("p1") String x,@QueryParam("p2") String y)
    {
        return String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(x)+Integer.parseInt(y));
    }
}
```

please help me

this is my Exception :

```
Sep 24, 2019 3:06:03 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  controller
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scan(FileSchemeScanner.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:226)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:142)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

please help .

Answer (score 0):

you must submit params: expamle: {p1:'2' , p2:'5'}